# Laravel Echo with Pusher for multiple users

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm building an app that will let users accept meeting requests. A user could have multiple calendars, for different locations they have to manage. Furthermore new calendars associated with a user can be added at any time.

I'm not seeing how a user could subscribe to an arbitrary number of channels-- it seems like you have to create an explicit client-side listener for any channel(s) and event you want to monitor:

```
public function getListeners()
{
    return [
        "echo-private:calendars.{$this->calendarId}, CalendarEventCreated" => 'notifyNewCalendarEvent',
    ];
}
```

Since there's multiple event types (eg. `CalendarEventCreated`, `CalendarEventRejected`, `CalendarEventUpdated`) per calendar, and potentially dozens of calendars per user, how can this be structured so there's not hundreds of listeners running for each user?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to broadcast data on the user_id directly, providing the calendar id and event info. But this only really works for the calendar owner, or you'd need to broadcast to all users with view rights on the calendar separately.

The other solution is to stick with your description. Is it really a problem to listen to 100 events? In the end, you'll only have a dozen channels open that need authentication on server side, and only 1 websocket connection open. Once authenticated on a channel, you'll receive messages anyway, whether you are listening for them or not.

The trick is to make your frontend code as clean and DRY as possible. Personally I use Vue, Vuex and vuex-orm a lot, where the orm is mirroring the data structure I have in my backend. When data is inserted into the frontend orm, a callback is run where I have my webhook logic. When data is removed, a callback is run where I leave channels etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge `CalendarEventCreated`, `CalendarEventRejected`, `CalendarEventUpdated` into `CalendarEvent` and then provide the type of event with the payload. Basically one can use one channel per user or one channel per calendar; sure the scheduling and listening is whole different, but overall not any more or less events / listeners (assuming both approaches work equally well).